# No funciona php al enlazar con html

Tags: php, html

tengo un archivo html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <li>
                <a href="archivo.php"></a>
            </li>

    </body>
</html>
```

y otro php

```
echo "¡Hola, soy un script de PHP!";
```

pero al ejecutar aparece un cuadrado negro y pequeño mire en la consola de internet y no me aparece ningún error

probé hacer lo todo en el mismo archivo y ahí directamente no me aparecía nada y no aparecía ningún error alguien sabe que puede estar pasando

Comment: Ya le pones el `<?php` al inicio del archivo antes del `echo`?  ¿y tiene extension PHP? ¿y tienes un interprete de PHP en tu servidor web que gestione los php?

Comment: Verificaste si el nombre del archivo es tal cual lo que pones en tu href? Verificaste si es la ruta correcta? prueba con `/archivo.php`. También, en tu archivo `archivo.php` colocala etiqueta  `<?php` al inicio y `?>` al final.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev la etiqueta `?>` al final del archivo está [desaconsejada](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#22-files)

Comment: @masterguru claro, solamente en casos de que haya únicamente código php.